# about RestKit 0.20.x caching policy

Tags: caching, restkit, policy

I'm unclear how to use the RESTKit 0.20.x API to set the request caching policy?

0.20.x not support caching policy?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

RestKit uses AFNetworking for the underlying network comms so you might want to look at [this doc](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ#does-afnetworking-have-any-caching-mechanisms-built-in).

In general, yes, RestKit uses the standard caching offered by `NSURLCache`.

Comment: NSURLCache class cached in memory, it seems RESTKit data in memory can not be mapping

Thanks